# one page to another page using flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

how to one page to another page without opening new window only url changed using flex?for example you can click log in button user name and password correct then going to home page without opening new window at the same window.. any one give example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it sounds as if you want to open a URL from within your Flex application within the same active window/tab.  Using the navigateToURL function and passing '_self' will achieve this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"), '_self');
```

Comment: i got this error Error: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before rightbrace